# Camera and video control with HTML5 form android webview

Tags: html, webview, camera

I use this guide : [Camera and video control with HTML5](https://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera)

This example work excellent on Google Chrome but i can not make it work on Android webview. I also use permission : android.permission.CAMERA.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add your code?

Comment: @Dany Maor Why did I not get the bounty ? Gave you a working example + explenation

Comment: Did you ever found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to add this to your `onCreate`

```
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
```

You are probably missing the last two lines in your code.

Here is a working [example](http://www.flapjacksandcode.com/blog/2015/2/17/android-webviews-getusermedia-putting-it-all-together)

Answer (score 0):

Webview/ Android browser till recently support ways to access camera via webview. Thankfully now getUserMedia is supported

http://caniuse.com/#search=Accept
http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream