# Enable camera access via the input file

Tags: cordova

I'm using InAppBrowser, to open an external form.

In this form there is an input file, so that the person can take a photo and attach it to the form.

When I access the link through the browser, the access of the cell phone camera works correctly, but when I access it via InAppBrowser or an iframe, the input file does not open the camera.

Is it necessary to enable some resource in the cord so that the camera can be accessed via InAppBrowser or iframe?

```
<script>
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
            cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://apps.url.com/index.php', '_blank', 'location=no');

            navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
                popoverOptions: new CameraPopoverOptions(300, 300, 100, 100, Camera.PopoverArrowDirection.ARROW_ANY, 300, 600)
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Plugins being used:

```
"cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
"cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-media-capture": "^3.0.3",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

In appbrowser is also a webview, without additional parameters you will not be able to access the camera.

For example:

[Camera and video control with HTML5 form android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547889/camera-and-video-control-with-html5-form-android-webview)

I'm not sure whether new cordova updates provide those properties. But i have found some plugins that fix that: https://github.com/jverlee/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-camera

Comment: The parameters informed in the link, are to be used in java and not in cord. Can you edit your post and put an example?

Comment: @Tiago i tried to tell you, that you need such parameters, but as im concerned from CORDOVA documentation those parameters are not implemented for InAppBroser. So you need to: 1) Write your own plugin 2) Customize the existing plugin 3) Install plugin from a second link for example